Question downvoted with no feedback - how to improve?
I would like to ask for your help in order to understand what I did wrong and/or could have done better in my last question.
The question was about a bad SQLite query generated by the Laravel framework, due to a mistake I made and have since corrected, but which did not generate an exception as I would have expected, so I decided to ask how can I have similar queries generate a better recognizable error.
First I had posted only the generated SQL query, together with my opinion on why it did not generate ad actual error but only returned an empty result set; then, I added also my PHP/Laravel code which generated the part of the query responsible for the unexpected behaviour.
I would like to understand why is it considered a bad question, and how I can improve; also, if it is so bad/wrong, I also tried deleting it, but SO won't let me; I've noticed now that there is also a close vote with the "needs details" reason, but I am not sure what further details should I add.

in the first revision there is no laravel code, right?

That is correct, I added it after feedback from a user on https://stackoverflow.com/a/78646788/1443080, and I agreed it  was useful to add context, since I was looking for a root solution in Laravel.

Perhaps what was unclear is that I was NOT asking "why" that specific query did what it did, but how to have the framework generate a "better" query for it.

@rene - I don't a MRE in this revision..  The author is also in a rollback war with another user, over an edit which invalidates an answer to the question, the edit in question does indeed invalidate the answer to the question they received.

So, voters watch the active tab of [tag:laravel], click on the question: they see only sqlite crap. Why are you surprised voters hit the downvote button? It took you 30 minutes to get a better revision in.

I do not understand, what is the problem with SQLite?

@SecurityHound what do you mean with "I don't a MRE"? What does the acronym mean?

There is no laravel code in the 1st rev. That is the problem.

MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Ok, I take that as a fact, but WHY is it a problem? I added it seconds later.

.. not seconds, but some minutes, after the feedback I explained I received.

You asked the question at 2024-06-20 09:56:49Z and your edit was done at 2024-06-20 10:24:04Z that's around 30 minutes which is probably enough for quite a few users see  the question and downvote since the question lacked Laravel code which is what the question was apparently trying to debug.

You are right, it was later than I remembered; however, the downvotes arrived quite later; most of them actually appeared after I asked this question here XD

You got one extra dv. It was at 3 dv when I arrived at the timeline: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78646762/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries

I feel like all this comes down to a miscommunication with the user who first answer me, who claimed that "The user subsequently changed the question, incorporating my answer.", but I did no such thing.

Another problem is that in the time you took to edit an answer was posted considering your question a SQLite question. Your edit then invalidated this answer, that obviously will irritate users (even people other than the answerer).

@rene yes, that is true, but I do not think that is my point... you stated There is no laravel code in the 1st rev. That is the problem., to which I agreed and explained that I later fixed the question, before any downvote happening, and I am still trying to understand what is wrong with it as it is now.

@AbdulAzizBarkat from the very first revision of the question, as it was stated, I never asked for an explanation of why that specific query behaved as it did; if a user answers without understanding the actual question, I can understand the frustration, but that shouldn't warrant such reaction.

@MatteoTassinari I do agree that answerer mistook your question for what it was not, but that probably ties back into your missing Laravel code. It is best to take your time to improve the question before you ask it rather than editing later and fixing things.

The question was clearly not about having an explanation on the query result from revision 1: Is there a way to solve this problem by acting on Laravel's or SQLite's configuration? right at the and of the first revision... How can this mess be fixed now? It won't allow me to simply delete and reask as given as answer in other cases.

@MatteoTassinari - Just because you did not specifically ask about the query behavior, does not mean that somebody with more knowledge of how the query ran, wouldn't provide that explanation. Deleting your question to avoid downvotes would be toxic behavior.  This is one of many reasons your question cannot be deleted. The other reason is it received an answer with multiple upvotes. Deleting the question and just asking it again, would result in the new question, being closed as a duplicate of your original question

"How can this mess be fixed now" a few downvotes don't mean much in the long run if the Q&A is good / useful. I can't judge whether the quality of the Q&A though since I'm not an SME in Laravel.

"most of them actually appeared after I asked this question here" that is to be expected; you have actively drawn attention to your question to the part of the community that is the most active in curation, resulting in something known as the "Meta Effect". Posts that are referenced here often get additional votes (both up and down) as many users here actually use their votes.

What is the meta effect?

@ThomA I understand the whole issue with "attracting attention", but how does down voting without explanation help me (or anyone else) to fix whatever problem granted the down vote itself? It is quite frustrating doing wrong without knowing what is actually wrong and how to fix it, hence my question here.

Anyway, thanks everyone for your help; tomorrow, with a clear mind, I'll try to give another look at the question trying to improve it

Unfortunately the only reward for returning to a question to see if it has been improved is the warm and fuzzy feeling you get from a job well done, so you can't count on initial downvotes ever going away. You have to wait for future users to stumble across the post and learn from it.

@SecurityHound my intent in deleting it was not for the down votes, as the effect of those on my score is negligible; I simply thought that a down voted question was unsuitable for this site, hence better remove it and clean up. I wouldn't have reposted it.

@MatteoTassinari - If you have improved the quality of the question then those that have cast a downvote can reverse it.  If you delete the question, then that cannot be accomplished.

Mini 2cts feedback: I regularly DV Qt's with a "How to" Title and no question mark.., SO is mostly to answer "How to...?" Qt's, not to share "How-to" tutorials... // + "quoted column" in the Title doesn't really make sense to me... (12 years on SO, 18k-Rep and 400 Answers, you should know how quality-Qt's are constructed...) // (I still UV'ed both your Qt and Answer, finding the negative Scores "a bit too harsh" for the quality provided... - to compensate a bit the 'Meta'-effect...)

Thanks for your feedback; I'd like to ask you too: would it make sense to go back and try a complete overhaul of the question? Or is it better to just keep it closed and maybe ask a new better one?

From the question:

Is there a way to solve this problem by acting on Laravel's or SQLite's configuration?

This is extremely unclear.
What problem? I assume you mean "the fact that the wrong query was generated". But - why is this query wrong? You say that "company_id does not exist in companies; however, the query does not generate an error when run, it just returns no result." - but you don't explain why that is a wrong result. What you describe makes perfect sense: if you ask me to find everything that matches a certain description, and nothing matches that description, then I think your request is well formed, and I also think I'm perfectly correct in showing you no results.
You say that "I suppose the problem here is that "company_id" is treated as a literal instead of a column reference"; but why is that a problem? Why shouldn't company_id be treated that way?
What result do you think you should get when the generated query runs, and why do you think you should get that result?
I also can't understand what you mean by "acting on", nor why it should make sense to try to do things that way. The purpose of Laravel is that it is supposed to generate a correct query for you (i.e., one that is automatically used by the system, and gives you an appropriate result) - right? So, if you don't get the result you want, and there's actual logic behind wanting the result that you want, then the problem is in the input step. Unless you think there's an actual bug in Laravel - in which case you should be at the project's issue tracker, not here.

This is also missing context. Don't use links to refer to "my previous question" - if you link a previous question, it should be to cite something that you're saying in the current question, which should be something that you learned the last time around. This way, it can actually be useful to others. Please keep in mind that this is not a discussion forum; the question is not about you, nor about solving the problem in your code, but about contributing to a Q&A library.
Please also keep in mind the value of a proper minimal reproducible example. We expect questions to be self-contained. That means you should start by showing the input to Laravel, and also giving enough background that we should understand what you expect to happen when the code runs. It also means including, for example, some sample data for the database, so that we can understand what result you expect from that data.

Thanks for you answer, I understand that I gave way too many things for granted, and that I should have spelled them out explicitely instead; I will remember this next time I post a question here, however, for this specific one, I do not think it'd make sense to rewrite it more clearly, or would it?

It absolutely does IMO.

@MatteoTassinari You're on Stack Overflow, a site which is increasingly more vilified online because it dares to not only set but also enforce quality standards. Rewriting it to be more clear is exactly what is expected of you.

If improving the quality of questions/answers is the goal, then downvoters should be required to add a comment explaining how they could actually be improved. New users facing an avalanche of downvotes with no explanations are left in the dark. SO's reputation is vilified online not for enforcing high quality standards, but partly for the lack of clarifications on downvotes.

@LucMorin this has been discussed to death and is now covered in the Meta FAQ.

@KarlKnechtel I know it has, but it still feels like some people are trigger happy to downvote without giving any explanation. I understand the reasons given by the community with regards to commenting on downvotes, but I remain on my position that trigger happy downvoters should be "educated" by moderators, at least when they display a clear pattern of doing so. I'll leave it at that.
